# How to find a file in Emacs without known exact directory?

Tags: emacs

In vim it's very easy to find a file without knowing which directory the file is in. Doing this ":args **/file.hpp" if the file exists, it will get it open.

Is there any substitution in Emacs to do so? The find-file seems work for wildcards, but it doesn't do the tricky like vim does with `**`.

Answer (score 35, accepted):

`M-x find-name-dired` looks like what You want (You will be prompted for root directory to start search with and a file mask)

Comment: Thanks for help!

It looks more likely without external plugin, emacs is not very handy to do that like vim.

Comment: Is it work under windows environment? I got this error message:   k:/DataHubs/Dropbox/Dropbox/development/:
  find . "(" -iname "*.ds" ")" -exec ls -ld {} ";"
   आ ऐ ऊअआऐ ॊ ऊऎ: "*.ds"
  
  find exited abnormally with code 2 at Sun Aug 21 11:51:06

Answer (score 5):

A more blunt but still handy tool: `M-x locate`

Using OS X? This makes emacs use spotlight instead of the standard `locate`:

```
(setq locate-command "mdfind")
```

Comment: Probably not. But you can use "locate" instead, or any modern replacement.

Answer (score 5):

A good tip if you use `ido-find-file`:
From a known root directory, you can use `ido-wide-find-file-or-pop-dir`, which by default is bound to <kbd>M-f</kbd>.

Answer (score 2):

[FindFileInProject](http://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/FindFileInProject) may also be worth looking at.

Answer (score 2):

In **Icicles** you can find files by matching not just the relative file name but any parts of the path.  You can use substring, regexp, and fuzzy matching.  You can AND together multiple search patterns (progressive completion).  See multi-command `icicle-locate-file`.  And you can even search against file contents, as well as or instead of file name.

http://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/Icicles_-_File-Name_Input

Answer (score 0):

I like

```
M-x ifind /some/path/to/start/file.hpp
```

or just

```
M-x ifind file.hpp
```

using the [ifind package found here](http://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/ifind-mode.el).  Note: it does open up a `*ifind*` buffer which displays the results, which you can either select with the mouse, or navigate using <kbd>C-x `</kbd> (aka <kbd>M-x next-error</kbd>).